# Specifying font size for the text passed as an argument in a newcommand

Tags: macros, fontsize, awesome-cv

I'm using the [awesome-cv](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) template and I'm trying to change the following code within the templates .cls file:

```
% Defines writer's mobile (optional)
% Usage: \mobile{<mobile number>} 
\newcommand*{\mobile}[1]{\def\@mobile{#1}}
```

I'd like to add a \fontsize command to the \mobile command. Here is a \newcommand that does precisely that, also in the .cls file of the template.

```
 \newcommand*{\headerfirstnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{30pt}{1em}\headerfontlight\color{graytext} #1}}
```

I've tried with the same syntax on the \mobile command but it has no effect on the document.

The purpose of this is to make the font larger of the section marked in red which is defined by the commands \mobile \email \homepage etc:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: You may need to add `\selectfont` after concluding the `\fontsize` command.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You could try `\makeatletter\renewcommand*\mobile[1]{\def\@mobile{\begingroup\fontsize{30pt}{1em}\selectfont #1\endgroup}}\makeatother`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for changing the *whole* section marked in red is the following:

```
\newcommand*{\mobile}[1]{\def\@mobile{\fontsize{12pt}{}\selectfont #1}}
```

Credit to Steven B. Segletes